# I'm trying to implement Screenshare but getting this error: MediaError "Access to screen denied"

Tags: webrtc, agora.io

I am using the Web SDK for Agora.io and trying to implement video chat feature and have screen sharing enabled. However, I am getting this issue:
MediaError "Access to screen denied

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your web page does not have the right to access the device. Not sure which browser you are working with. If your browser is Chrome/Chromium, try: [Change site permissions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Or test your browser with their tools: [Agora Web Trouble shooting](https://webdemo.agora.io/agora_webrtc_troubleshooting/), [Agora Web Demo](https://webdemo.agora.io/videocall/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome or Firefox with Agora.io to screenshare. Make sure that you are deploying to HTTPS.

Firefox:

```
screenStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
    streamID: uid,
    audio: false,
    video: false,
    screen: true,
    mediaSource: 'screen' // 'screen', 'application', 'window'
});
```

Chrome:

```
screenStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
    streamID: uid,
    audio: false,
    video: false,
    screen: true,
    //chrome extension ID
    extensionId: 'EXTENTION-ID-HERE'
});
```

Are you using Chrome? Check a few things:

1. Check that the extension ID matches
2. Check the domain name matches in the manifest.json file

[Chrome Plugin Reference page](https://docs.agora.io/en/2.3.1/product/Interactive%20Broadcast/Quickstart%20Guide/chrome_screensharing_plugin)